# LoadError: cannot load such file ... in simple Ruby script

Tags: ruby, rubygems, load

I installed a new gem, 'zoom_rb' with

```
gem install zoom_rb
```

Listing the local gems shows zoom_rb installed. When I try to run a script starting with `require 'zoom_rb'`, or if I do the same thing in IRB, I get the error

```
D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require': cannot load such file -- zoom_rb (LoadError)
    from D:/Ruby24-x64/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from test.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

Is there a general approach to debugging these "cannot load such file" problems? Is there more information in some log about why it could not be loaded?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the readme but it has changed since. It's `require 'zoom'` now instead of `require 'zoom_rb'`